# git init fails on vfat usb stick

Tags: git, ubuntu

I suddenly cannot write to my bare git repository on a vfat usb stick/disk anymore.
The error message is "remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Vorgang nicht zulässig"

It seems to be related to group writing access permissions on the vfat disk

I then tried with two different sticks to create a git repository there with:

```
git init
```

or even

```
sudo git init
```

This fails with the error message:
fatal: Konnte Gruppenschreibrecht für /media/disk/gittest/.git/hooks/ nicht setzen.

which means: can't set group write permissions on the .git/hooks dir

I then even tried to mount the disk on my own with

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/disk -o rw,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002
```

to make sure I have group write permissions, but still the same problem.
ls -lat then shows:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 rolf rolf 32768 Okt 19 12:32 .git
drwxrwxr-x  3 rolf rolf 32768 Okt 19 12:32 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 rolf rolf 32768 Jan  1  1970 ..
```

As I understand vfat has no explicit group write permissions anyway, but this all worked well for years, and I don't know whether ubuntu or git changed here to create this problem.

git is version 2.17.1
ubuntu is 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: It looks like the issue is not related to git.

Comment: Using `sudo` is a terrible idea, you don't want to run `git` as root and you will end up with files not owned by your own account if it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to mount the vfat disk with a different gid:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/disk -o rw,users,uid=1000,gid=users,umask=002
```

I tried several other groups: users(100), nogrp (65534), test(1001)
With all of those git init works, but with my own group (1000) it does not work.